Why is [static 1] not used everywhere in C?
I saw a Video about modern C programming, and one topic was that when you use [static 1] with a parameter, it indicates to the reader and the compiler that a pointer should never be NULL.
You would use it like this:
void foo(int my_ptr[static 1]) {
    // my_ptr should never be NULL
}

instead of:
void foo(int* my_ptr) {
    // my_ptr can be NULL
}

If you enable -Wnonnull, it even throws a warning when you pass NULL to the first option.
My question is, why is this not common practice and used everywhere?
I don't think this can or should replace NULL checks, but it certainly would be useful, nevertheless, IMO.
I also heard that compilers might remove NULL checks if they see that the pointer should never be NULL because of the [static 1], which would be bad, but I don't know if this is true.

People don't know it yet. Compilers don't know it yet. All code was written in the past, some before this feature existed.

Hint: you can even do void foo(int n, int a[static n]); to say that array a has n elements or more.

@UlrichEckhardt but is there a reason not to use it today? It works well with GCC.

in the question you are asking "why is [static 1] not used everywhere", or "why this is not common practice", not "are there any reasons not to use it today".

@MikeNakis ok sorry, but I meant why is it not used today. I thought it was obvious because I mentioned that it was in a Video about modern C programming.

@Finn Pretty much the only reasons to write a brand new program in C anymore are variations on the theme of "C gives you more portability and more backwards compatibility than any other language at the same level of abstraction from the hardware." But to get those advantages you have to avoid using the shiny new features of C post-1999 without checking for their availability first and having a fallback. The upshot is that almost nobody ever writes "modern C".


Although this was introduced as early as C99, as mentioned in an answer here What does the static keyword do in C?, compilers had very poor support for this until just a few years back, around the time when that post was written (around gcc 11/clang 13).

Compilers are only able to do this check caller-side for compile-time constants. It has no effect on run-time assigned pointers, making the feature less useful and misleading even, if the programmer thinks they are now safe from null pointers.

Good program design is to do checks against null pointers at the point where something risk becoming a null pointer. And not in some unrelated function later on. For example, the check should be done after calling some function that might return a null pointer.
Adding a null pointer check inside some unrelated function on the other hand, introduces a branch which is useless overhead in case the caller is not passing trash parameters to the function. Which can turn out very expensive if the function is called repeatedly from a loop etc.


So it really boils down to: that parameter shouldn't be null anyway. Or otherwise there's a caller-side bug. However, [static 1] might serve as self-documenting code, telling the caller "I'm not doing any null pointer checks here so you better not pass me garbage parameters". That's generally the spirit of C - to leave error handling to the caller.
